# Addition of menuitem in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, menuitem

I want to add the below menu **(code-2)** under a tab present **(code -1)** on my HTML page. But it is not showing up/displaying under the tab area.

I have the .css style also included in my **code-2** so this may be the cause. Can anyone suggest me how can I correct this? Is this occuring because of two divs one for tab and other for menuitem in my page?

**Tab in my HTML page- Code 1**

```
</div>
  <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_2" style="height:500px">

  //Want to insert the menucode in this area but not getting any content displayed.      
</div>
```

**My menu code: Code-2**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example of HTML Menu</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      #horizontalmenu ul {
        padding:1; margin:1; list-style:none;
      }
      #horizontalmenu li {
        float:left; position:relative; padding-right:100; display:block;
        border:4px solid #CC55FF; 
        border-style:inset;
      }
      #horizontalmenu li ul {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
      }
      #horizontalmenu li:hover ul{
        display:block;
        background:red;
        height:auto; width:8em; 
      }
      #horizontalmenu li ul li{
        clear:both;
        border-style:none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="horizontalmenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">News</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">National</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sport</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hollybood</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Technology</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">IT/Software</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hardware</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Iphone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Neuro-Science</a></li>
          </ul>                    
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sports</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Cricket</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tenis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Badminton</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hockey</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Country</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">India</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">America</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pakistaan</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Problematic code

```
<head>
  <title>Example of HTML Menu</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen" hef = "mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="horizontalmenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">News</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">National</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sport</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hollybood</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Technology</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">IT/Software</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hardware</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Iphone</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Neuro-Science</a></li>
        </ul>                   
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sports</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Cricket</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tenis</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Badminton</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hockey</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Country</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">India</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">America</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pakistaan</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

So are you trying to insert the whole "Code-2"? You don't need to insert `<html><head><body>` tags..

Just insert:

```
    <div id="horizontalmenu">
        <ul> <li><a href="#">News</a>
                <ul> <li><a href="#">National</a></li> <li><a href="#">International</a></li> <li><a href="#">Sport</a></li> <li><a href="#">Hollybood</a></li> </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="#">Technology</a>
        <ul> <li><a href="#">IT/Software</a></li> <li><a href="#">Hardware</a></li> <li><a href="#">Iphone</a></li> <li><a href="#">Neuro-Science</a></li> </ul>

            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="#">Sports</a>
                <ul> <li><a href="#">Cricket</a></li> <li><a href="#">Tenis</a></li> <li><a href="#">Badminton</a></li> <li><a href="#">Hockey</a></li> </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="#">Country</a>
                <ul> <li><a href="#">India</a></li> <li><a href="#">America</a></li> <li><a href="#">France</a></li> <li><a href="#">Pakistaan</a></li> </ul>

            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

And import the styles you have in the head section.

Comment: I tried the one you suggested but it didnt work. I have pasted the code under the heading "Problem Causing Section" in my original thread.